# Anchor environtment variable

Tags: anchor, solana

When I make an `anchor test` or `anchor build` I've this error:

```
BPF SDK: \\?\C:\Users\user\.local\share\solana\install\releases\1.9.4\solana-release\bin\sdk\bpf
Can't get home directory path: environment variable not found
```

solana version 1.9.4
anchor-cli 0.23.0

Comment: I've added a global environment variable and user environment  variable as HOME=path/to/project/acnchor but doesn't work

Comment: I've tried with WSL2 and when I make an anchor build the error is : error: no such subcommand: `build-bpf`

Comment: Rernandez I would higly recommend WSL if you prefer windows system for development

Answer (score 0):

If you want `$HOME` defined, you likely need to run `anchor test` / `anchor build` from a Bash-compatible shell.  Git bash is a great option for Windows, and I've had success with it in the past when not using WSL: https://gitforwindows.org/

Answer (score 0):

Use WSL and dont use the latest Solana CLI suite, use the stable version.

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install)"
```